# Is there any way to use discord.py decorators in the class?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have just simple bot

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all())
    
    @self.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.user} is now running!')
        # some functions

    @self.event
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # some functions


bot = MyBot()
load_dotenv()
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

But when I run this it says

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

I also tried using

> @bot.event

It says

> NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

Is there any way to use decorators in a class?

Comment: Just get rid of the decorator altogether. The `@event` decorator just copies the function into the class. You don't need to copy the function into the class since it's already in the class.

Comment: @Gaberocksall thank you very much, but is it also true, if I want to use "@bot.tree.command(name='b', description='a')" some of these decorators?

Comment: You cannot use the decorator like that since it requires the `bot.tree` to already exist, which it won't while you're creating the class. Instead, you can add it to the `__init__` like `self.b = self.tree.command(name="b", description="a")(self.b)`

Comment: `commands.Bot` isn't generally designed to be subclassed - consider using [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v2.3.1/ext/commands/cogs.html).

Comment: If you want to define `discord.py` events in a cog, use `@commands.Cog.listener()`